# How to quickly check a SQL connection without waiting 30 seconds for connection.open();

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlconnection

If I've got a connection string based on user input and I want to quickly determine if it's a valid input. I've done some research and it seems people use `.Open()` to check the connection. However in my console app this check takes ~30 seconds before throwing the catch statement. Is there a faster way to do this?

**EDIT**: A few of you have suggested setting the timeout to a low value like 1. Isn't this cause for concern? Considering the default is set to *30* I'd be afraid of timing out too early on a valid - yet slow - connection.

Here's my code if you need it:

```
while (sqlManager == null)
{
    try
    {
        sqlManager = new SqlManager(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    catch
    {
        sqlManager = null;
        Console.WriteLine("values entered could not be used to establish a connection, please try again: ");
    }
}
public class SqlManager
{
    public SqlManager(string userEntry)
    {
        string server;
        string db;
        if (userEntry == "")
        {
            server = Properties.Settings.Default.SqlServer;
            db = Properties.Settings.Default.SqlDatabase;
        }
        else
        {
            var splits = userEntry.Split(' ');
            server = splits[0];
            db = splits[1];
        }
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection($"Server= {server}; Database= {db}; Integrated Security=True;");
        con.Open();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would love to know if there's a faster way. It's very annoying to basically hang for 30 seconds any time the user made a typo...

Comment: the connection timeout can be configured

Comment: Set the connection timeout =1

Comment: Well, do you mean the input *looks* valid, or that it is an actual/real SQL connection? You could probably configure some regex to see if it looks valid for quick validation. But if you're talking about seeing if the connection is real, you probably need to test Open with a low timeout.

Comment: The latter, don't care how it looks. Just want to know if a connection is made or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `ConnectionTimeout` property to define a shorter wait time:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout(v=vs.110).aspx

The default is 15 or 30 seconds, the current documentation mentions 15... You can set it to any larger or smaller number. 0 would mean to wait infinitely.

Actually changing the default is a bit tricky, because the `ConnectionTimeout` property on the `SqlConnection` class is read-only. You have to specify it as a part of the connection string, or use a connection string builder, like this:

```
var connstr = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
{
    DataSource = "servername",
    IntegratedSecurity = true,
    ApplicationIntent = ApplicationIntent.ReadOnly,
    ApplicationName = "appname",
    InitialCatalog = "db",
    ConnectTimeout = 2
}.ConnectionString;

using (var conn = new SqlConnection { ConnectionString = connstr })
{                        
    conn.Open();
}
```

Comment: Is this really the best way? I'm just concerned because if I set it to something fast like 1 I'd be concerned that a valid connection might throw this as an invalid one just because the connection was slow.. Especially considering the default has been set to 30!

Comment: @CapnJack well, how else could you tell the difference between a server that is slow and a server that is not responding. It is not only the best way, but really the only way.

Comment: you're talking about a command-line tool... if you time-out on first attempt with 1 or 2 seconds timeout, give the user a choice like "retry connection attempt with longer time-out".

Comment: Well I was hoping one of you could tell me lol.. I guess I have to use the timeout method. Thanks!

Comment: Can't tell if I'm stupid or this doesn't work. `SqlConnection.ConnectionTimeout` doesn't seem to have a set option. EDIT: nvm you have to do it in the connection string.

Comment: @dlatikay No I know that, I used `con.ConnectionTimeout` but look in the documentation you linked. Even there it says there's no `set` access modifier

Comment: Hey thanks, this looks promising. Just a question, my connecting string on sql server management studio is `localhost\testserver myDataBase`. Would I be correct in saying `DataSource = "localhost"`, `ApplicationName = "testserver"`, `InitialCatalog = "myDataBase"`?

Comment: @CapnJack `localhost\testserver` is not the same thing as `DataSource = "localhost", ApplicationName = "testserver"` the actual name of the server is the full combined name. ApplicationName is used for easier debugging and seing which apps opened which connection.

Comment: the part after the backslash is the instance name, and it goes with the server name. so you would have `DataSource = @"localhost\testserver"` and `InitialCatalog = "myDataBase"`.

Comment: @dlatikay yeah got it now thanks sir. So I'm curious what is the `ApplicationName` used for if anything?

Comment: It becomes a part of the session descriptor (SPID) on the server and is shown to admins/operators when they view active connections so they know where the connection came from. It ends up in the `APP_NAME()` system function.

Comment: Very helpful.  For me, ConnectTimeout did not work directly in connection string, but "Connection Timeout=5" did.  Found this at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout